# Cannot submit form with a hidden input in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

so I have a form that contains a hidden input.

```
 <?= $this->Form->create(null, [ 'class' => '', 'templates' => 'Inspinia.form_basic']) ?>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->control('name');
        echo $this->Form->control('description', ['type' => 'text']);
        echo $this->Form->control('chart_type', [ 'options' => $this->App->availableCharts() ] );
        echo $this->Form->control('frequency', [ 'options' => ['monthly' => 'Monthly','quarterly'=>'Quarterly','snapshot' =>'Snapshot','monthly/quarterly' => 'Monthly/Quarterly'] ] );
        echo $this->Form->control('public', [ 'options' => ['1' => 'Public','0' => 'Private'] ] );
        // $this->Form->unlockField('deleted');
        echo $this->Form->hidden('deleted',['value' => 0]);
    ?>
<?= $this->Form->button(__('Save'), ['class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Whenever I try to submit the form, it throws me this error

```
Missing field 'deleted' in POST data
```

I know I can bypass this by just doing

```
$this->Form->unlockField('deleted');
```

but I don't want to bypass the security component in Cakephp, so is there any other way I can get CakePhp to allow me to submit this hidden field?

this is my controller nothing too much but here just in case you guys are wondering

```
public function test() {

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        debug($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$this->Form->hidden('deleted'); `

OR 

`$this->Form->input('deleted', ['type' => 'hidden']);`

Comment: @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan I already have that in there

Comment: `echo  $form->hidden( 'Model.name', array( 'value' => 'fieldvalue' ) ); `

take a look at this

http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/06/23/working-with-forms/

Comment: I copied your code and it works: if I `debug($this->request_data())` I see the field. Sure you don't have some other code in the middle? Also 'missing field in POST' does not sound as a cake error to me. Where exactly is it generated?

Comment: @arilia there's no code in the middle, must be a environment issue, I'll check that now

Answer (score 1):

It should like below

```
<?php
  echo $this->Form->input('nameoffield',array('type'=>'hidden')); 
?>
```

or passing a hidden value

```
<?php
$hidden_value = 0;
echo $this->Form->input('nameoffield',array('type'=>'hidden','value' => $hidden_value)); 
?>
```

Comment: I made it look like that and still threw me the same error

Comment: does the "deleted" field present in your table? if not please add this field